# Upload file with geb

Tags: groovy, selenium-webdriver, geb

all!
I want upload file on my test. On [Geb-book](http://www.gebish.org/manual/0.9.0-RC-1/navigator.html#file_upload) write how it make, but it's doesn't work for me.

I have field:

```
<input id="bla-bl-bla" type="file" name="foo-foo-foo">
```

And button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Загрузить файл" name="bar-bar-bar">
```

I try:

```
    def "choose banner format"() {
    when: "choose fake format"
        $("select", name: Const.namespaceId + "createBanner:j_id83:j_id91")
    and: "wait load"
        waitFor(25, 2) { $("input", name : Const.namespaceId + "createBanner:upload:j_id256")}
    then: "can upload file"
        $("input", id : "name") << name_banner
        String file_1 = "/full/path/to/file"
        String uploadfile = "foo-foo-foo"
        $("input").uploadfile  =  banner
        $("input", name : "bar-bar-bar").click()
        def createActLink = $("input", name : "save")
        createActLink.click()
        sleep 20000
}
```

But I have error:

```
Expected a condition, but found an assignment. Did you intend to write '==' ?
```

Geb: 0.9.0-RC-1
Groovy: 2.1.1
Browser: FF 19

Thank you!

Comment: What's the full code for the test?

Comment: The `then:` block is for asserting the test completed successfully, I think you need another `and:` block, or just put all that code in the `when:` block. You don't seem to be testing anything for success. See the _'when and then blocks'_ section [on this page](https://code.google.com/p/spock/wiki/SpockBasics)

Comment: you think , if i put code to another block, this code start works?

Comment: @tim_yates I move this code to `and:` but I have error 
`groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: uploadfile for class: geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator
 at geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator.propertyMissing(NonEmptyNavigator.groovy:442)`

Comment: You need `def uploadfile = "foo-foo-foo"` though I can't see that you use it at all...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27010/discussion-between-plsgogame-and-tim-yates)

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should seriously consider rewriting this code using the Page model as explained [here](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#pages). It will make life a lot easier for you. Though if all you want is to get the code working, try something like this...

```
def "choose banner format"() {

    given:
        String file_1 = "/full/path/to/file"
        String uploadfile = "foo-foo-foo"
    when: 
        //if j_id83 and j_id91 are integers, caste them to strings!
        $("select", name: Const.namespaceId.toString() + "createBanner:j_id83:j_id91")
        waitFor(25, 2) { $("input", name : Const.namespaceId + "createBanner:upload:j_id256")}
        $("input", id : "name") << name_banner
        $("input").uploadfile  =  banner
        $("input", name : "bar-bar-bar").click()
        waitFor{ $("input", name : "save") }
        def createActLink = $("input", name : "save")
        createActLink.click()
    then:
        waitFor{
          // choose an element to refresh on page after input is clicked   
        } 
}
```